# Vimeo-api response body empty

Tags: node.js, vimeo-api

I'm using vimeo-api for node.js from here https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js
I want to do simple video search request, but while following example and doing everything almost identical, I stumbled upon some problems

Code:

```
, Vimeo = require('vimeo-api').Vimeo;

var lib = new Vimeo(*myapp id*, *my app secret*);

lib.generateClientCredentials('public', function (err, access_token) {

if (err) {
    throw err;
}
console.log('credentials generated')

var token = access_token.access_token;
console.log(token);
lib.access_token = *token, generated in my app authentication tab on vimeo developer()*;
    var scopes = access_token.scope;
console.log(scopes);
});

client.on('vimeocall', function (qinput) {
      console.log('got vimeo call');
      lib.request(/*options*/{
      // This is the path for the videos contained within the staff picks channels
      path: '/videos',
      // This adds the parameters to request page two, and 10 items per page
      query: {
          query: qinput,              
          per_page: 10
      }
  }, /*callback*/function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
      if (error) {
          console.log('error');
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          console.log('body');
          console.log(body);              
      }

      console.log('status code');
      console.log(status_code);
      console.log('headers');
      console.log(headers);
  });
})
```

So, first problem is, that console logs in `generateClientCredentials` prints, that `token` and `scopes` is undefind;
Then I manually put there pregenerated token, to test it further.
Second problem - callback from `lib.request` logs `status code 200`, `headers` with data, but embty `body` - just body {}.
Testing on localhost.
Where I messed up?

**Update:**
`headers` prompts:

```
{ date: 'Thu, 16 Oct 2014 15:48:44 GMT',
server: 'Apache',
'set-cookie': [ 'vuid=1338193217.1277890698; expires=Sun, 13-Oct-2024 15:48:44
GMT; path=/; domain=.vimeo.com' ],
vary: 'Accept,Vimeo-Client-Id,Accept-Encoding',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, max-age=315360000',
expires: 'Sun, 13 Oct 2024 15:48:44 GMT',
'keep-alive': 'timeout=100, max=88',
connection: 'Keep-Alive',
'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
'content-type': 'application/vnd.vimeo.video+json',
 via: '1.1 dca1-10' }
```

Comment: The full callback signature of the generateClientCredentials callback is fn(err, body, status, headers). What value do you receive for each of those items?

Comment: Hey there, well, no error, body {}, status_code 200, headers - added they promt in question.

Comment: Yet waiting for some useful info

Comment: Unfortunately I've never seen this issue before. Try modifying the vimeo hosts to proxy your requests through runscope.com. Their tools might be able to help pinpoint the exact issue. If not, runscope lets you share your requests. You should share your requests with https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: It always heartwarming, when solution comes from the place, way too simple and easy, that in your mind it's almost doomed to be useless attempt.    
Just updated node.js to the latest version - 0.10.32 x64 version on Windows 8. Now everything seems to work perfectly, credentials generated and `body` is full of awesome stuff. Thx for replys, Dashron.

Comment: By the way a bit unrelated question, if you don't mind, I can't understand in what case will I need to generate those credentials on my server. I can just get them from my app developer page. And I'm using this API for pretty simple stuff - just searching and filtering Vimeo wideos on web site.

Comment: Client credentials are unauthenticated tokens. They do not have access to private content, and are useful to users who might expose these tokens to the public. Authenticated access tokens can be generated through the redirect flow on behalf of any user on vimeo.com, whereas the app page tokens are only generated for the application owner.

Comment: But if we are talking about unauthenticated tokens - client credentials, that need to be generated for app. Then why do i need to generate them via lib.generateClientCredentials if I just can get them from my app page? Or is it just options to chose from?

Comment: App page tokens are authenticated. Requests made from that token can see all of your private content. ClientCredentials are unauthenticated, and have no association to a user account.